# scala: how to convert ArrayBuffer to a Set?

Tags: scala, collections

I've been looking for a bit of time on how to convert an `ArrayBuffer` to a `Set`, an `HashSet` I guess to be precise. Any hint?

Comment: Search is your friend on scaladoc. If you typed "set" on the method list, you'd be given a list of 13 methods, where it would have been much easier to spot `toSet`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `toSet` function implemented in [ArrayBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer)

Example:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> import collection.immutable.HashSet
import collection.immutable.HashSet

scala> val a = new ArrayBuffer(2)
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Nothing] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> val b = a.toSet
b: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing] = Set()
```

Comment: Crazy, I looked at the scaladoc but missed it and eclipse didn't want to auto complete my last array to be able to figure out how to convert it
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

To Set:

```
scala> val bf = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4)
bf: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> bf.toSet
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

To HashSet:

```
scala> val hs = new HashSet[Int]++ bf.toSet
hs: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: The second example is redundant. They do pretty much the same, with the exception that `toSet` will use specialized classes for `Set`s instead of `HashSet` for less than 5 elements: `ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4).toSet.isInstanceOf[HashSet[_]] == false`, `ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5).toSet.isInstanceOf[HashSet[_]] == true`

Comment: @soc thanks for comment -- didn't know about less-that-5-elements specialization

Answer (score 3):

For completeness' sake, one more way:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val as = ArrayBuffer(34, 89, 11)
as: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(34, 89, 11)

scala> Set(as: _*)
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(34, 89, 11)
```

Comment: I tried this Set(array: _*) but for some reasons it didn't work. Glad to see it should have :)